# watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck when booting (Arch) Linux on MINISFORUM N4020

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, grub

The above behavior *only* occurs when **cold starting** the device. Entering and leaving BIOS already circumvents the problem. **But** so does pressing `ctrl+alt+del` when the grub menu is shown. Any other approach - like multiple combinations of options in BIOS - did not work for me.

**Update:** The device crashed **when on duty** and rebooted constantly with an uptime between 10 minutes and 3 hours. It's currently under investigation again, but **seems stable without network/load**. Memtest passes 4 rounds error-free.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find out anything else?

Comment: @RandomAndy: Since my workaround seems tho have "solved" my problem I was not in need for further research. But I plan to do a full re-powering- test in the next weeks, i.e., simulate a power loss on the rack with switches and routers affected. If that does not work as expected I will (have to) either do more research or replace the device in the rack and use the N4020 for some other duties. I'll post an update if I find something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a bit and "solved" (circumvented) this by first "booting" into a reboot and starting the linux kernel afterwards:

> /etc/default/grub
>
> ```
> GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
> GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
> ...
> ```

> /etc/grub.d/05_minisforum_reboot
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> exec tail -n +3 $0
> menuentry "MINISFORUM BOOTFIX" {
>    echo "Provoking a reboot and then booting the FIRST remaining option (#1)..."
>    echo "This circumvents the soft locks errors/crash on COLD (power on) boot!"
>    set saved_entry=1
>    save_env saved_entry
>    sleep 5 #remove to save 5 more seconds on boot
>    reboot
> }
> ```

> root:crontab -e
>
> ```
> @reboot /usr/bin/grub-set-default 0 #set the default back to MINISFORUM BOOTFIX
> ```

This way also the `Power On` BIOS option works fine, so the device flawlessly boots into Linux when (re)powered.

I'm still happy for **real** Solutions to this problem. My guess would be somewhere between a thermal issue or some initialization problems with the eMMC.

Answer (score 0):

soft lockup is a Linux kernel bug, when some task can cause threads to loop and the kernel does not release activity to other processes.
updating the kernel seems like a only workaround.

run:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

OR

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

**Install kernel updates on a Ubuntu LTS server**

Type the following apt-get command:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If a new kernel installed, reboot the Linux server:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

check if it still occurs